# Is it possible to assign patterns to certain nodepart elements?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pattern, tikz-node

It is possible to assign color to individual nodepart elements.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,patterns}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[stack/.style={
                rectangle split, 
                rectangle split parts=4,
                rectangle split part fill={red!40,blue!40,green!40,yellow!40},
                draw}]
        \node [stack] (mystack) {
            \nodepart{one}\small{Foo}
            \nodepart{two}\small{Bar}
            \nodepart{three}\small{Baz}
            \nodepart{four}\small{Qux}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to assign patterns in a similar way? I tried with `rectangle split part pattern` already but it does not work like that.

Comment: Can you please complete your code to be compileable (with as little code as possible but still complete)? It's called MWE on this site (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Yes it is. First declare pgf layers. And then use node-anchors to draw a rectangle on the background layer. And then fill this rectangle with whatever pattern you want.

Comment: @Symbol1 That would be a 'No', then. That can hardly be considered 'similar' to the method shown in the question for filling, can it?

Comment: @cfr It is impossible to use a *similar* mechanism because in the declaration of  `rectangle split`, see `pgflibraryshapes.multipart.code.tex` line 985, 986, 1064, 1065, it uses `\pgfsetfillcolor` to set the fill color. If you want to apply pattern, you should have `\pgfsetfillpattern` at that point instead.

Comment: I think I just slap myself in the face.

Comment: @Symbol1 ??? I wasn't for a moment suggesting whatever you think I was suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a free workaround that might destroy everything

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,patterns}

\begin{document}
    \makeatletter
    \begin{tikzpicture}[stack/.style={
                scale=3,
                rectangle split, 
                rectangle split parts=4,
                /utils/exec={
                    \def\pgfsetfillcolor##1{
                        \message{^^J^^J The "color" is \string##1= ##1 ^^J^^J}
                        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pgfsetfillpattern##1
                    }
                },
                rectangle split part fill={
                    {fivepointed stars}{red},
                    {fivepointed stars}{blue},
                    {fivepointed stars}{green},
                    {fivepointed stars}{yellow}
                },
                draw}]
        \node [stack] (mystack) {
            \nodepart{one}\small{Foo}
            \nodepart{two}\small{Bar}
            \nodepart{three}\small{Baz}
            \nodepart{four}\small{Qux}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]